# How to write the Java hasNext() function for custom scanners

Tags: java, io

I've found a number of custom Scanner classes on the internet for fast Java IO, but none of them offer a custom hasNext() method implementation, so I don't know how to read data when input is of variable size.

Here's an example of one of these classes:

```
class Reader {
static BufferedReader reader;
static StringTokenizer tokenizer;

/** call this method to initialize reader for InputStream */
static void init(InputStream input) {
    reader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(input) );
    tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("");
}

/** get next word */
static String next() throws IOException {
    while ( ! tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ) {
        //TODO add check for eof if necessary
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
               reader.readLine() );
    }
    return tokenizer.nextToken();
}

static int nextInt() throws IOException {
    return Integer.parseInt( next() );
}

static double nextDouble() throws IOException {
    return Double.parseDouble( next() );
}
}
```

How could I go about writing this myself? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the BufferedReader doesn't have a `hasNext()` function but it includes a `ready()` function which is a boolean function that tells if there is an input to be read or not, You can find about it here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready-- .

So if you want to added to the class you mentioned it will go like this :

```
static boolean ready() throws IOException {return reader.ready();}
```

However take care if the input is not present `ready()` will return false.